# How to get Markdown processed content in Jekyll tag plugin

Tags: jekyll, liquid, octopress, jekyll-extensions

I'm working on a Jekyll tag plugin for my Octopress site to help me make a 'note' element.  I just want to be able to highlight a piece of information on my blog as a side note, like this.

[image]

The problem is, I can't figure out how to get the contents of this tag to be processed (i.e. Markdown or Textile).  The above image is only achieved is I actually make my links with html code.  Here is how it ends up turning out when I use markdown in the contents.

[image]

In my post, I'm writing the contents of this like so.

```
{% note %}
This is the third post in my Start to Finish series.  Last time I talked about [Git](/blog/2013/09/25/getting-started-with-git/).
{% endnote %}
```

Here is my plugin code.  It's based off of the image tag code, and there's really not a lot to it.

```
module Jekyll
  class NoteTag < Liquid::Block
    @title = nil

    def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
      @title = markup
      super
    end

    def render(context)
      output = super(context)
      title = "Note"
      if !@title.empty?
        title += ": #{@title}"
      end
      "</section>\n<div class=\"note\"><span class=\"title\">#{title}</span>#{output}</div>\n<section>"
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('note', Jekyll::NoteTag)
```

Do you have any idea how I can use a converter on the contents of this tag?  I generally use Markdown for my posts, but I'd like to release this plugin for others so I'd like it to be dynamic just like the rest of Jekyll.

Comment: have you managed to find the answer? I'm running into the same brick wall right now and haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jekyll 3.x : **getConverterImpl** is now deprecated

Use **find_converter_instance** to get the converter :

```
def render(context)
  text = super
  site = context.registers[:site]
  converter = site.find_converter_instance(::Jekyll::Converters::Markdown)
 _output += "<figcaption>#{converter.convert(_caption)}</figcaption>"
```

Answer (score 12):

I found this implementation of a '[Markdown block tag](https://github.com/imathis/jekyll-markdown-block/blob/master/lib/jekyll-markdown-block.rb)' which seems to be a relatively straightforward implementation. Note the use of `site.getConverterImpl()` in the `render` method.

I used that example to produce this figure tag (based on prior art to another question I found on SO but can no longer locate)

```
module Jekyll
  module Tags
    class FigureTag < Liquid::Block

      CaptionUrl = /(\S[\S\s]*)\s+(https?:\/\/\S+)\s+(.+)/i
      Caption = /(\S[\S\s]*)/

      def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
        super
        @caption = nil
        if markup =~ CaptionUrl
          @caption = "\n\t\t<figcaption>#{$1}<a href='#{$2}'>#{$3}</a></figcaption>\n\t"
        elsif markup =~ Caption
          @caption = "\n\t\t<figcaption>#{$1}</figcaption>\n\t"
        end
        @markup = markup
      end

      def render(context)
        site = context.registers[:site]
        converter = site.getConverterImpl(::Jekyll::Converters::Markdown)
        output = converter.convert(super(context))
        "<figure class=\"center\">#{output}#{@caption}</figure>"
      end
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('fig', Jekyll::Tags::FigureTag)
```

The above plugin manages to parse markdown within the contents of the block. So given the following block tag usage:

```
{% fig Test fig %}
This should be parsed as *markdown* [man](http://example.com/).
{% endfig %}
```

You'll get the following html:

```
<figure class="center"><p>This should be parsed as <em>markdown</em> <a href="http://example.com/">man</a>.</p>
    <figcaption>Test fig </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Hope this helps! I spent a couple hours last night and got nowhere, but this morning I found this example and it clicked within 20 minutes.

Comment: OMG, you just saved me a ton of time. Thank you! It's funny, because I was wanting to do the exact same thing (`<figure>` plugin). For my code, I just wanted to apply my chosen markdown converter to just the caption via the output in my `render` method; this is all it took: `_output += "<figcaption>#{converter.convert(_caption)}</figcaption>" if _caption`. Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: Just as a small addition: In Jekyll 3.x the method `getConverterImpl` was renamed to `get_converter_instance`. See [here](https://github.com/operasoftware/devopera/pull/269)