# Access markup-free post and page content from Jekyll plugins

Tags: jekyll

I’m working on a plugin to parse all posts and gather them into a JSON file to be consumed by a search mechanism. **How can I access just the text of the post, with no markup?** I’m currently accessing `site.posts`, then e.g. `page.content` in loops. This returns the content of the post, but includes newline markers (`\n`) and Markdown syntax.

I saw another question in which someone wanted to [get Markdown processed content in a Jekyll tag plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169849/how-to-get-markdown-processed-content-in-jekyll-tag-plugin), but my case is different: I don't want any markup at all, just the plain text of the post, with no formatting applied.

Below is the key `def` from my current implementation.

```rb
def generate(site)
  target = File.open('js/searchcontent.js', 'w')
  target.truncate(target.size)
  target.puts('var tipuesearch = {"pages": [')

  all_but_last, last = site.posts[0..-2], site.posts.last

  # Process all posts but the last one
  all_but_last.each do |page|
    tp_page = TipuePage.new(
      page.data['title'],
      "#{page.data['tags']} #{page.data['categories']}",
      page.url,
      page.content
    )
    target.puts(tp_page.to_json + ',')
  end

  # Do the last post
  tp_page = TipuePage.new(
    last.data['title'],
    "#{last.data['tags']} #{last.data['categories']}",
    last.url,
    last.content
  )
  target.puts(tp_page.to_json)

  target.puts(']};')
  target.close
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this :

```
{{ page.content | strip_html | strip_newlines }}
```

**Edit** obviously I misunderstood you question.

But you can use Liquid filters with `include Liquid::StandardFilters`

You can then use `strip_html` and `strip_newlines` in your plugin.

Comment: Those are Liquid filters, which are not accessible from a plugin Ruby script. I need to do this entirely within this plugin file.